# JQuery dropdown works on Firefox but not on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome

First the code might suck as I'm new with JQuery. I have this html:

```
<select name="numberItems" id="id_numberItems"> 
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option> 
<option value="2">2</option> 
<option value="3">3</option> 
<option value="4">4</option> 
<option value="5">5</option> 
</select>
<fieldset class="dropdownList"> 
     [...]
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="dropdownList"> 
     [...]
</fieldset>  <!-- This fieldset is repeated 5 times -->
```

This is my Jquery code:

```
// Dropdown
function dropDown(val) {
    $('.dropdownList').hide();
    $('.dropdownList:lt(' + val + ')').show();
}

$("#id_numberItems").click(function() { dropDown($('#id_numberItems').val()) });
```

This dropDown thing is working on Firefox, but not in Google Chrome ¿why? Thanks

Comment: Open up your page with Chrome, "Ctrl + Shift + J" -> Console, click your dropdown and look what's wrong in the console. Maybe that can provide some useful information.

Comment: do you have a demo page?

Comment: I have tried CTRL + Shift + J but I don't know hot to debug inline scripts, it is not in a separate file. With FireBug in Firefox debugging goes smooth.

Comment: I don't have a demo page right now, I'm working on a local dev server. I could try to set up one with some time if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach your dropDown-function to the `change`-event of your dropdown and it should work the way you want it (or as my crystal ball suggests me...)

```
$("#id_numberItems").change(function() { dropDown($('#id_numberItems').val()) });
```

[example on jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/emipa3)

Comment: I'm not sure what the spec says about the onclick-behaviour of a select-element. Chrome won't invoke the click-event of the select when you click an option as the other browsers are. On the first click after page loading you get '1' as value because of the "pre-selection". Next time you click the select you get the value of the previous selection and so on. So if there is no special reason you should always use the onchange-event.

Comment: The change event is also a better choice here in terms of accessibility, because it will get called regardless of whether the user is interacting with the page via a mouse or keyboard.